# How to use group audience in drupal 7 views filters

Tags: organic-groups

How to use the Group audience field in our drupal 7 views filter. I have to fetch the values for the appropriate groups node. So i want to add the group audience field in the views filter. By default the filter having the fields of Groups audience (group_audience:gid), Groups audience(group_audience:delta) likewise. Please suggest me some ideas how to fetch the values based on the group audience field in the views filter.

Thanks, Sathish

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Please check the screenshot.Basically you need to add a relationship as in screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

First You need to add a relationship in view, for that follow the below procedure..
1. Click on Advanced button which is on right hand side.
2. Click on Add a relationship.
3. search for the og from node and add it.

Here it is done.
Now, Add the filter criteria, it will available in this.
:)